# Some files get uploaded using input file tag some not

Tags: php, html

I am unable to upload files using html  control.

lets suppose i have two image files 
image1.jpg and image2.jpg

image1 gets uploaded
image2 doesn't

Everything is fine with image1 ,the same code gets called for image2 but image2 is not uploaded.
It is not giving any error.

There is no upload restriction like file size and/or extension.
I have also changed the php.ini with changes in maxpostsize,uploadsize and memory limit.
Please help out, I have been searching this thing for three days but never got the reply.

```
if(isset($_POST['submitBtn']))
{
$title=$_POST['titleTxt'];
mysql_query("INSERT into tblsliderphotos (title) values('$title')") or 
die(mysql_error());

    if($_FILES['file']['name']!="")
    {
    //echo $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $tblData=mysql_query("Select MAX(photoid) as id from tblsliderphotos");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($tblData);

    $id=$row['id'];

    $path="photos/SliderPhotos/". $id.".".$image_ext;
    echo $path;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"../../".$path);
    mysql_query("Update tblsliderphotos SET path='".$path."' where 
photoid=".$id);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you absolutely sure, that you don't have anything inside the $_FILES variable at the start of your script and you don't accidentaly remove the value somehow later within the script?

Comment: You are doing multiple things a the same time. Do the file-uploading handling first, put database interaction into a class of it's own so it's easier to just process the request.

Comment: Thanx for help.
But i said that some kinds of file get accepted and uploaded but some not, even the file which is uploaded also updates the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is not with php env. but with your upload file handling.

let's suppose your html code something like below

```
<form action="someaction" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="title" />
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="file" name="file2" />
<input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now, you have to notice there is two input of type "file", first one have name value "file", and the second have name value "file2".

When you want to deal with both, you have to handle every file alone. as below:

```
$_FILES['file'] // this will give you information about the first input "file"

$_FILES['file2'] // this will give you information about the second input "file2"
```

Now, when you want to upload both of files, you have to do this for each. as below:

```
 // handling first file
if($_FILES['file']){
   echo $_FILES['file']['name'];
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"../../".$path);
}

// handling second file
if($_FILES['file2']){
   echo $_FILES['file2']['name'];
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file2"]["tmp_name"],"../../".$path);
}
```

This will upload both of files to your $path

However you can do same thing with looping over $_FILES variable, as below:

```
 foreach($_FILES as $key => $value){
     echo $key."\r\n";
     echo $value['name'];
     move_uploaded_file($value["tmp_name"],"../../".$path);
 }
```

I hope this help

Comment: Thankx for the help Mohammad Ahmad.
Probably you didnt understand the question.

I use one control only.
Sometimes it uploads the file sometimes not.

Comment: Mohammad Ahmad your answer gave me a hint.
I added a check on $_FILES['file']['name']that it possesses a value or not and uploaded the file according to that condition.
worked for me

thanx for the help